# Setting Firebase user display name via new Firebase console

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-console

A basic question I'm sure, but I can see how to programatically set user details of a Firebase user, but I just want to set the display name of a user manually via the Firebase console. I just see the basic 5 columns (email, signed in, providers, created, UID), with no obvious options elsewhere.

Comment: There is currently, and annoyingly, no option to set the display name via the Firebase Auth console. It has to be done programatically.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks. Seems very strange.

Comment: still no option to set manually as of now :(

Comment: or now latest update :/

Comment: You can add a user collection in Firestore and can add other details of every user in document of that collection. Now you can edit that collection anytime from your database.But for this you need to call the user's details everytime from the firebase database.

Comment: This very old comment was not about Firestore - I'm not even sure Firestore existed when this was written. It was regarding the realtime database..

Comment: 2021 and still nope

Comment: You can't just set the displayName for users who signed up with providers like Google, Facebook but should have the option to set for the email provider. Also wondering why not just have a "view details" option to show the respective user data.

Comment: There are various features which are intentionally not developed by Firebase. For example, (1) Setting user details from Firebase console (2) Searching feature in Dynamic links (3) etc.

Answer (score 0):

As of June 2023, there is still not a way to do this through the Firebase console. You'll unfortunately still need to [use code to update display names](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile):

```js
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

user.updateProfile({
  displayName: "Jane Q. User",
  photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
}).then(() => {
  // Update successful
  // ...
}).catch((error) => {
  // An error occurred
  // ...
});
```